# Status bar, navbar margin

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode6, statusbar, navigationbar

I'm adding my searchController to my current controller, it's working fine when I'm using xcode 5.1.1, but when I upgraded to xcode 6, it gives me problem. I notice that it doesn't count the status bar's height in UI, in the homepage it doesn't count the height of navbar too. but when I go to second page, it counts the height of status bar and nav bar.

`CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 44)` this is the frame of my searchBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve this by getting the frame of the added child controller by getting it's height and add or subtract.

`CGRect frame = searchView.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y += 64; // add or subtract
        searchView.view.frame = frame;`

I think this is not the proper way, any suggestion guys ?

Did xcode 6 didn't count the statusBar's height and navigationBar's height ?